# Get values of uEye Camera

Tags: c#, camera

Was wondering if anyone knew anything about uEye cameras.

I am using one for a application I am creating, I am wanting to get the colour values from this camera for certain areas of the image.

I am currently using

```
Int32 s32MemID;
Int32 s32Red;
Int32 s32Green;
Int32 s32Blue;
Camera.Memory.GetActive(out s32MemID);

Camera.Image.GetValues(s32MemID, uEye.Defines.ColorMode.RGB10Unpacked, width, height, out s32Red, out s32Green, out s32Blue);
```

to get the colours, however this only gets the values from the width and height given. I want to be able to set the position also.

Any one got any ideas on how to do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting directly the bitmap and proccesing it latter? The TextOnBitmap example in the uEye page shows how to do so in the btn_text_to_bitmap method.
https://en.ids-imaging.com/programming-examples.html